# wifi scanner shows no result or slow proccess

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I wrote an application to capture the wifi access points info. I do not understand why some times it scanning do not have any result while when I turn off and on the wifi in the phone settings I can observe all of the access points there. 
more over is there any way to get the result of wifi scanning faster?! like what the phone does when turning on the wifi in the phone settings.  I made the result specific for an access point called "UMCH_Network"
thanks

this is my .java file content:

```
package com.example.wps;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView mainText;
TextView notifText;
EditText eTxtnumberOfTimes;
EditText eTxtDistance;

WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiReceiver wifiReceiver;
List<ScanResult> wifiList;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Handler handler = new Handler();
String DirectoryName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notifText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvMain);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

public void ScanAndDraw(View v) {
    scanwifi();
}

public void scanwifi() {
    wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    notifText.setText("Scanning ...");
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult result : wifiList) {
            if (result.SSID.equals("UMCH_Network")) {
                sb.append("Distance: " + eTxtDistance.getText().toString()
                        + "\t");
                sb.append("Number of Times: "
                        + eTxtnumberOfTimes.getText().toString() + "\t");
                sb.append("Level:\t" + result.level + "\t");
                // n=4.48 d0=3meter
                sb.append("estimated distance in meter: "
                        + (3 * (Math.pow(10, (-result.level - 46) / 44.8)))
                        + "\n");
            }
            notifText.setText(sb);
        }

        //mainText.setText(sb);
        notifText.setText("");
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mo) {
    // float x = mo.getX();
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is the content of manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantly show a list of wifi recently scanned by using this code,

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> apList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

Comment: it works very fast but does not seem to get updated even wen I restart my app! Is there any way to make it updated? @nikvs

Comment: On starting the app instantly you can show a list using the above code.At the same time register a broadcast receiver for wifi scanning and update the list in on receive method.

Comment: This will be similar to my previously written code. Is it the only way?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, this is the only method.If I come across any other way,will surely let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem..finally i got solution

> Get Wifi Scan results method needs GPS to be ON and COARSE location
>   permission in Manifestfile.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#enableNetwork

I hope this will helpful

Comment: @Hossein Dolatabadi please check my updated answer still if you are 
required.